# mysql how to update a field only if new value is lower then the existing value

Tags: mysql

I'd like to update the value of a field only if the new one is lower. I tried min like this, without success

```
UPDATE `editions` SET `editions`.`year`  = MIN(`editions`.`year` , '2005')  WHERE `editions`.`id` = 1;
```

I get a 1064 error. How can I update the value without retrieving the value first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing it like this:

```
update editions set year = 2005 where id = 1 and year > 2005;
```

(i.e. restrict the selection to row(s) that you would want updated)

Comment: So obvious, how could I not have thought at this. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE `editions` 
SET `editions`.`year` = 
LEAST(`editions`.`year` , '2005')  WHERE `editions`.`id` = 1;
```

Comment: +1, as it's what I was looking for, but Mat's answer is the way to go. Thanks